# (Non-Relational) DBMS Design Resource

Tags: nosql, low-level, database, non-relational-database

As a personal project, I'm looking to build a rudimentary DBMS. I've read the relevant sections in Elmasri & Navathe (5ed), but could use a more focused text- something a bit more practical and detail-oriented, with real-world recommendations- as E&N only went so deep.

The rub is that I want to play with novel non-relational data models. While a lot of E&N was great- indexing implementation details in particular- the more advanced DBMS implementation was only targeted to a relational model.

I'd like to defer staring at DBMS source for a while if I can until I've got a better foundation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to understand the properties of each system. i can offer you to read this [post](http://www.vineetgupta.com/2010/01/nosql-databases-part-1-landscape.html). it's the first step to understand NOSQL or Not Only SQL.Secondly you can check  this [blog post](http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems) to understand all these stuff visually.

Finally glance at open source projects such as Mongodb, Couchdb etc. to see the list you can go [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-nosql-databases)

Comment: Yes, reading the source of open projects will help understanding the limitations or benefits of any method.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the first step would be to understand hierarchal, network, navigational, object models which are alternatives to relational.  I'm not sure where XML fits in i.e. what model it is.  As far as structure, research B-tree (not binary trees) implementation.

Comment: I understand the logical models I'm interested in, but needed more on how non-relational DBMSs are physically implemented. B-trees (specifically B+trees) have been very useful, but don't make an entire DBMS. 

I've resorted to scanning the source of popular projects, and playing with a number of different libraries that give me the on-disk structures I need. Right now, I'm fooling around with Tokyo Cabinet's b+tree, hash, and fixed-length databases, which have been very helpful building blocks.